# Передача данных из дочернего компонента в родительский Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Доброго времении суток.

Суть вопроса в следующем.

Имеется компонент **BaseField**:

```
<template>
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label has-text-white" v-text="title"></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input
                class="input is-pretty"
                :type="type"
                :name="name"
                :placeholder="tip"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'BaseField',

        props: {
            title: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },

            type: {
                type: String,
                default: 'text',
                required: false
            },

            name: {
                type: String,
            },

            tip: {
                type: String,
                default: '...',
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

В свою же очередь есть некий враппер над формой **BaseModel**

```
<template>
    <div class="modal is-active">
        <div class="modal-back"></div>
        <div class="modal-card is-image is-shine">
            <header class="modal-card-head is-opacity has-text-centered">
                <p class="modal-card-title has-text-white is-uppercase"><slot name="title"></slot></p>
            </header>
            <section class="modal-card-body is-opacity">
                <form method="POST" :action="action">
                    <slot name="fields"></slot>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'BaseModal',

        props: {
            action: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Теперь мы все это дело закатываем:

```
<base-modal action="/login">
            <template slot="title">Авторизация</template>
            <template slot="fields">
                <base-field title="Логин" name="username" tip="Введите Ваш логин"></base-field>
                <base-field title="Пароль" name="password" tip="Введите Ваш пароль"></base-field>
            </template>
        </base-modal>
```

**Вопрос**

Не могу понять, каким образом можно собрать все введеные в **BaseModel**

Пробовал через $emit как то ловить, но что то не особо получалось, не могу осилить этот момент

Спасибо :)

Comment: А что именно у вас с `emit` не получалось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вдруг комуто нужно, то нашел ответ от Эвана Ю.

Есть несколько вариантов решений:

Если большая вложенность компонентов, то лучше всего решить задачу через **Event Bus**, но если прибегли к автобусу ивентов, то уже можно рассмотреть **Vuex**

В моем же случае, я знаю точно, что BaseField будет точно лежать в BaseModal и выше передавать значение мне не нужно, значит можно решить таким макаром:

**BaseField**

```
<template>
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label has-text-white" v-text="title"></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input
                class="input is-pretty"
                :type="type"
                :name="name"
                :placeholder="tip"
                @blur="updateFieldValue($event.target.value)"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'BaseField',

        props: {
            title: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },

            type: {
                type: String,
                default: 'text',
                required: false
            },

            name: {
                type: String,
            },

            tip: {
                type: String,
                default: '...',
            }
        },

        methods: {
            updateFieldValue(value) {
                this.$parent.$emit('field:change', {
                    name: this.name,
                    value: value
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**BaseModal**

```
<template>
    <div class="modal is-active">
        <div class="modal-back"></div>
        <div class="modal-card is-image is-shine">
            <header class="modal-card-head is-opacity has-text-centered">
                <p class="modal-card-title has-text-white is-uppercase"><slot name="title"></slot></p>
            </header>
            <section class="modal-card-body is-opacity">
                <form method="POST" :action="action" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
                    <slot name="fields"></slot>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'BaseModal',

        props: {
            action: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {
                fields: {}
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.$on('field:change', value => {
                console.log(value);
            });
        },
    }
</script>
```

Итого, что мы сделали? В дочернем элементе указали, что хотим отправить родителю ивент:

```
this.$parent.$emit('field:change', {name: this.name, value: value});
```

А в родительском компоненте, при его создании, начали слушать потомка:

```
this.$on('field:change', value => console.log(value));
```

Теперь осталось в родительском компоненте красиво обыграть работу с полями, например создать класс **Fields**, где будем записывать\обновлять\удалять и т.д.
наши инпуты и сабмитить их на сервер.

Вот такие дела :)

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант добавить инпуту атрибутом v-model="currentValue" и в самом компоненте.

```
data: function () {
    return {
      currentValue: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
    currentValue: function () {
      this.$emit("currentValue", this.currentValue ? this.currentValue : null)
    },
  },
```

Но я не знаю насколько это будет хорошим решением, но зато работающим) Если вызвать в родительском элементе через @currentValue=loginTyping то при вводе любых значений в инпут будут возвращаться его значения, которые можно привязать к дате в родительском компоненте. Но так же можно использовать $ref на дочерних компонентах и получать их данные.